# Activity Indicator does not Animate IOS

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

Activity indicator does not animate in my code. I have folowing code

How can i fix it? Is it because mean thread doesnt update indicator status? If so how can i fix it?

```
@interface ConnectionEstablishedViewController : UIViewController{
 IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * activityView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *loadingLabel;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)  UIActivityIndicatorView * activityView;
```

I have assigned both label and activity indicator in my.xib file

.m

```
- (void) threadStartAnimating {
    [activityView startAnimating];
    loadingLabel.hidden=YES;
}
- (void) threadStopAnimating {
    [activityView startAnimating];
    loadingLabel.hidden=NO;
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    [self threadStartAnimating];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];
    [self hunttable];//call hunttable in order to fetch hunt table data

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];//sleep to prevent thread from overlap

    [self huntingarea];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];

    [self stands]; 
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];

    [self weapons];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];

    [self backpack];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];

    [self descriptionget];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];

    [self threadStopAnimating];


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self threadStartAnimating];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    .
    ...//functions
    [self threadStopAnimating];


}
```

above should work